# xcolor: How to get the complementary color

Tags: color

Is there a LaTex-style way to get the [*complementary color*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors)? 
For example, a corresponding command in the `xcolor` package?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{book} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Acolor}{named}{red}
\definecolor{Bcolor}{named}{yellow}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{Acolor}{text} $\leftrightarrow$ \colorbox{gray}{complementary color here}

\colorbox{Bcolor}{text} $\leftrightarrow$ \colorbox{gray}{complementary color here}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Defining "complementary color" is not so easy ;-) (it depends on the model, you should have a look at section 6.3 of the [`xcolor` manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/xcolor/0)), but in a pinch, you can use the syntax `-color` as seen here (page 4 of the same manual):

[image]

So, your example:

```latex
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Acolor}{named}{red}
\definecolor{Bcolor}{named}{yellow}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{Acolor}{text} $\leftrightarrow$ \colorbox{-Acolor}{complementary color here}

\colorbox{Bcolor}{text} $\leftrightarrow$ \colorbox{-Bcolor}{complementary color here}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...and just for fun:

```latex
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Acolor}{named}{red}
\definecolor{Bcolor}{named}{yellow}
\definecolor{yellowrgb}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{yellowcmyk}{cmyk}{0,0,1,0}
\definecolor{yellowHsb}{Hsb}{60,1,1}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{Acolor}{text} $\leftrightarrow$ \colorbox{-Acolor}{complementary color here}

\colorbox{Bcolor}{text} $\leftrightarrow$ \colorbox{-Bcolor}{complementary color here}

\colorbox{yellowrgb}{text} $\leftrightarrow$ \colorbox{-yellowrgb}{complementary color here}

\colorbox{yellowcmyk}{text} $\leftrightarrow$ \colorbox{-yellowcmyk}{complementary color here}

\colorbox{yellowHsb}{text} $\leftrightarrow$ \colorbox{-yellowHsb}{complementary color here}

\end{document}
```

[image]